# send different values to SELECT via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box with cars and models.. When i select a car and model, i get prices for that cars..
Then i have a button to add a new car on the same form and page.. All this via jquery that sends id from car make to select query that returns all models.

The problem is, when i try to select the second car, i cant select a new make, because it uses the same id from the first make select option. So for my second car i get models from car make that i chosed on my first car...

```
my js:
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select#marca").change(function(){
var id = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
$.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
    $("select#modello").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select#modello").html(data);
    });

$('select#modello').change(function () {
var gruppo = $(this).attr('rel');
var id_tipo = $(this).val();
var id_referente = <?php echo $data['idAffiliato'];?>//$('#id_referente').val();
if(id_referente != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../handlers/handler_geo.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'action': 'getservizi', 'referente': id_referente, 'id_tipo': id_tipo, 'rnd': Math.random() },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success:function(data) {
                    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $('#elenco_servizi_'+gruppo).children().remove();
                    for(var c=0; c < data.length; c++) {
                    $('#elenco_servizi_'+gruppo).append('<li><input type="radio" rel="'+gruppo+'" class="validate[required] '+gruppo+'" name="servizi_'+gruppo+'[]" value="'+data[c].prezzo+'" title="'+data[c].id+'" /><span class="tipo-servizio">'+data[c].nome+'</span><span class="importo-servizio">&euro; '+data[c].prezzo+'</span></li>');
                    }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    } 
else {
        alert('attenzione, nessun referente disponbile per il servizio richiesto');
        }
});   
});
```

and my forms

```
<h5>Marca auto</h5>
<select id="marca">
<option label=" "></option>
<?php Auto::ShowMarca(); ?>
</select>
<br><br>
<h5>Modello auto</h5>
<select id="modello" rel="cb_1" name="tipologie_auto[]" class="validate[required]">
</select>
<br><br>
<?php $autos = Auto::ShowModello(); ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="servizio" id="gruppo_cb_1">
<h5>servizio</h5>
<ul id="elenco_servizi_cb_1" class="elenco_servizi">
<li><span class="tipo-servizio">seleziona la tipologia di veicolo per vedere i servizi</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="servizi_cb_1" name="servizi_cb_1" />
<span class="totale">&euro; <label id="lbl_cb_1">0</label></span>
</div>
</div>



<!-- ******************** auto 2 ******************** -->
<div id="auto_2" style="display:none;">
<h4>auto 2</h4>
<div class="right-col-prentivatore-form">
<div class="tipologia-auto">
<h5>Marca auto</h5>
<select id="marca">
<option label=" "></option>
<?php Auto::ShowMarca(); ?>
</select>
<br><br>
<h5>Modello auto</h5>
<select id="modello" rel="cb_2" name="tipologie_auto[]" class="validate[required]">
</select>
<br><br>
<?php $autos = Auto::ShowModello(); ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="servizio">
<h5>servizio</h5>
<ul id="elenco_servizi_cb_2" class="elenco_servizi">
<li><span class="tipo-servizio">seleziona la tipologia di veicolo per vedere i servizi</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="servizi_cb_2" name="servizi_cb_2" />
<span class="totale">&euro; <label id="lbl_cb_2">0</label></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so i get an id from MAKE (marca) and send it to SELECT query to select_type.php..

So, for the second car i'm sending the same id... How to make independent select boxes for two cars? THX

Comment: `id` attributes are supposed to be unique within the page.

Comment: Don't remove the content of your question after you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `<select>` elements with `id="modello"`, and the same for `id="marca"`, so your lines `$("select#marca")` and `$('select#modello')` will only take the first elements.

You have to reference these elements with a class.

Try this :

Your form :

```
<h5>Marca auto</h5>
<select class="marca">
<option label=" "></option>
<?php Auto::ShowMarca(); ?>
</select>
<br><br>
<h5>Modello auto</h5>
<select class="modello" rel="cb_1" name="tipologie_auto[]" class="validate[required]">
</select>
<br><br>
<?php $autos = Auto::ShowModello(); ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="servizio" id="gruppo_cb_1">
<h5>servizio</h5>
<ul id="elenco_servizi_cb_1" class="elenco_servizi">
<li><span class="tipo-servizio">seleziona la tipologia di veicolo per vedere i servizi</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="servizi_cb_1" name="servizi_cb_1" />
<span class="totale">&euro; <label id="lbl_cb_1">0</label></span>
</div>
</div>



<!-- ******************** auto 2 ******************** -->
<div id="auto_2" style="display:none;">
<h4>auto 2</h4>
<div class="right-col-prentivatore-form">
<div class="tipologia-auto">
<h5>Marca auto</h5>
<select class="marca">
<option label=" "></option>
<?php Auto::ShowMarca(); ?>
</select>
<br><br>
<h5>Modello auto</h5>
<select class="modello" rel="cb_2" name="tipologie_auto[]" class="validate[required]">
</select>
<br><br>
<?php $autos = Auto::ShowModello(); ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="servizio">
<h5>servizio</h5>
<ul id="elenco_servizi_cb_2" class="elenco_servizi">
<li><span class="tipo-servizio">seleziona la tipologia di veicolo per vedere i servizi</span></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="servizi_cb_2" name="servizi_cb_2" />
<span class="totale">&euro; <label id="lbl_cb_2">0</label></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Your JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.marca").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $(this).parent().find('select.modello').removeAttr("disabled");
            $(this).parent().find('select.modello').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('select.modello').change(function () {
        var gruppo = $(this).attr('rel');
        var id_tipo = $(this).val();
        var id_referente = <?php echo $data['idAffiliato'];?>//$('#id_referente').val();
        if(id_referente != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../handlers/handler_geo.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'action': 'getservizi', 'referente': id_referente, 'id_tipo': id_tipo, 'rnd': Math.random() },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success:function(data) {
                    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $('#elenco_servizi_'+gruppo).children().remove();
                    for(var c=0; c < data.length; c++) {
                        $('#elenco_servizi_'+gruppo).append('<li><input type="radio" rel="'+gruppo+'" class="validate[required] '+gruppo+'" name="servizi_'+gruppo+'[]" value="'+data[c].prezzo+'" title="'+data[c].id+'" /><span class="tipo-servizio">'+data[c].nome+'</span><span class="importo-servizio">&euro; '+data[c].prezzo+'</span></li>');
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('attenzione, nessun referente disponbile per il servizio richiesto');
        }
    });
});
```

I did not test, there might be other errors that I did not notice.

Comment: Thx alot,it worked. But when i select the make from second car,  the first selected model get blank and loose his value... What can i do?

Comment: Is there an online page where I can see your work ? Or is it possible to post your generated HTML code so I can test ? Because I can not have the datas with `<?php Auto::ShowMarca(); ?>` or other PHP lines.

Comment: @Adrian I edited my JS in the answer, there was a formatting problem in the code, the first `change` event was not closed. Try it and if it does not work with this, can you please go on your page, press Ctrl+U to show the source of the page and copy/paste the HTML code of your form, with this I will test on my computer without needing your database.

Comment: Did not understand your edit on my answer, do I have to delete the code ?

Comment: just wanted to delete my question (resolved). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different id for the second auto select. For example:

```
<select id="marca2">
```

Then re-use the JavaScript for auto 1 and replace the id `marca` with `marca2`. For example, here is how you can re-use the change function:

```
// Declare re-usable function that takes an id (eg. 'marca' or 'marca2')
var changeHandler = function(selectId) {
    var id = $('select#' + selectId + ' option:selected').attr('value');
    $.post('select_type.php', {id:id}, function(data) {
        $('select#modello').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('select#modello').html(data);
    });
};

// Change for marca
$("select#marca").change({ selectId: 'marca'},  function(event) {
    changeHandler(event.data.selectId);
});

// Change for marca2
$("select#marca2").change({ selectId: 'marca2'},  function(event) {
    changeHandler(event.data.selectId);
});
```

Comment: how to reuse that javascript?

Comment: sorry, didn't understood.. i'm new to jquery.. Where i insert the change for marca and marca 2?